# count internal and external edges of a subgraph

Tags: r, igraph

Given a non-directed graph `g` and a subset of vertices `v`,

I want to count:

- the number of (internal) edges of `g` connecting vertices in `v` to other vertices in `v`
- the number of (external) edges of `g` connecting vertices in `v` to vertices of `g` that are not in `v`

Is there an easy way to do this using an `igraph` function in R?

Reproducible example:

```
library(igraph)
g <- sample_gnp(100,0.5,directed = TRUE)
v = V(g)[1:10]
```

Comment: edited question to include reprex and clarified the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ends` function to find the vertices adjacent to an edge. If *both* ends of an edge are in v, it is an internal edge. If an edge has one but not both ends in v, it is external.

```
E1 = which(sapply(E(g), function(e) ends(g, e)[1]) %in% v)
E2 = which(sapply(E(g), function(e) ends(g, e)[2]) %in% v)

Internal = intersect(E1, E2)
External = setdiff(union(E1,E2), Internal)

## Spot check answer
 ends(g, Internal[10])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    3
> ends(g, External[20])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   13
```